# Trying to add a text to all cards in a dynamic page with Global Javascript via Google Optimize, but it's looping

Tags: javascript, css, loops, global-variables, google-optimize

Trying to add a text before the image on all cards, in a dynamic page. there are 1700 images so ı thought it's only doable via javascript, since it's on Google Optimize, only vanilla is allowed.

I put this:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll(".car-card .car-card__image");

images.forEach(function(image){ 
  image.before("Hello world");
});
```

It actually puts the text, but when I check it via debug mode, it's adding the text for forever, so I see,

Hello worldHello worldHello world....

How to fix this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you need create a empty tag before any image and put the text in it.

in yuor Html:

```
<div></div>
<img src="..." class="car-card">
```

and in yout javascrtipt code

```
document.querySelectorAll(".car-card .car-card__image").forEach(img=>{
    img.previousSibling.innerHTML = 'HELLO WORD';
})
```

But if you can't add a tag before the photo, there is another way that is not interesting

```
document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(img=>{
    var p = img.previousSibling;
    if( p && p.nodeName=='#text' )
        p.nodeValue = 'HELLO WORD';
    else
        img.before('HELLO WORD')
```

})

Comment: Hi Babak, thank you so much for the help,

But this added text to every image on the page, how can I make it only for the photos with the class name: "car-card__image" ?

Since there are thousands of car images, I can't put html code to each one of them I'm afraid. So I should use the last one...

I'm a newbie, so sorry if it's a silly question :(

Cheers